# mysql join query find min and max

Tags: mysql, sql

I have different table and want to fetch record based on left join. I have created query , but it will return only single row.

I have following tables:
sp_car_models whose foreign key is in sp_car_variants .
sp_car_variants whose foreign key is in sp_car_prices .
sp_car_variants whose foreign key is in sp_car_engine_transmission .

I want minimum price , minimum and maximum mileage

```
SELECT m.*, min(cet.mileage) as min_mileage, max(cet.mileage) as max_mileage, min(cp.price) as 
car_price FROM sp_car_models as m 
LEFT JOIN sp_car_variants as cv on cv.car_model_id = m.id 
LEFT JOIN sp_car_prices as cp on cp.car_variant_id = cv.id 
LEFT JOIN sp_car_engine_transmission as cet on cet.car_variant_id = cv.id 
WHERE m.car_brand_id = 1 and m.status = 1 
group by cv.id 
ORDER BY m.id DESC
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample as  tabular text  and the expected  result

Comment: It's usually wrong to group by a column in a `LEFT JOIN` table. You should probably have `GROUP BY m.id`.

Comment: Wow, `SELECT *` and `GROUP BY` ...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want, you should do INNER JOINs instead of those LEFT JOINs. (if not, you are assuming that those relationships can return no values and you should use the ifNull funtion while aggregating the results, and I think that is not the case). 
You need to do something like this:

```
SELECT 
  m.Id, 
  min(cet.mileage) as min_mileage, 
  max(cet.mileage) as max_mileage, 
  min(cp.price) as car_price 
FROM sp_car_models as m 
INNER JOIN sp_car_variants as cv on cv.car_model_id = m.id 
INNER JOIN sp_car_prices as cp on cp.car_variant_id = cv.id 
INNER JOIN sp_car_engine_transmission as cet on cet.car_variant_id = cv.id 
WHERE 
m.car_brand_id = 1 and m.status = 1 
group by m.id
ORDER BY m.id DESC
```

I'm not sure want you were trying to do with the group by cv.id. If what you need is to know those values by model and variant, than you should group by both properties, like this:

```
SELECT 
  m.Id, 
  cv.id,
  min(cet.mileage) as min_mileage, 
  max(cet.mileage) as max_mileage, 
  min(cp.price) as car_price 
FROM sp_car_models as m 
INNER JOIN sp_car_variants as cv on cv.car_model_id = m.id 
INNER JOIN sp_car_prices as cp on cp.car_variant_id = cv.id 
INNER JOIN sp_car_engine_transmission as cet on cet.car_variant_id = cv.id 
WHERE 
m.car_brand_id = 1 and m.status = 1 
group by m.id, cv.id
ORDER BY m.id, cv.id DESC
```

Comment: In other table may be value not present but we need to show model table rows. i.e used left join